# Introduction to batch scripting

Tags: windows, linux, shell, batch-file

This is my shell script

```
echo "Name"
read name
if [ "$name" == "abcd" ]; then
   echo "correct name"
else
    echo "wrong name"
fi

echo "Password"
read password
if [ "$password" == "pwd" ]; then
    echo "Correct password"
else
    echo "Wrong password"
fi

echo "City"
read city
if [ "$city" == "bangalore" ]; then
    echo "correct city"
else
    echo "wrong city"
fi
```

I'm totally new to batch scripting.How do i write an equivalent .bat file?

Comment: I don't understand why i got a down vote. I have no idea how to write an interactive batch script.

Comment: Is your question essentially "how do I do `echo "Name";read name` in a bat file?

Comment: Yes..That's exactly what i meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here for how to get input:
[Batch File Input](http://www.computing.net/answers/dos/making-a-bat-file-to-get-input/12821.html)

**Edit**: Link contents (no longer available) was:

```
    The following method will work on Windows 2000 and XP:

set INPUT=
set /P INPUT=Type input: %=%
echo Your input was: %INPUT%

If user hits ENTER without typing anything, the variable (in this case, %input%) keeps it value. So, the first line is to reset its value, so that if nothing is entered the variable will have no value at all, instead of some senseless value.

As you can see, that accepts blank inputs. You can make it to don't accept:

:input
set INPUT=
set /P INPUT=Type input: %=%
if "%INPUT%"=="" goto input
echo Your input was: %INPUT%

So, after getting user's input and saving it in a variable, you can use it as you will.
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you need to read up on:

- How to prompt for user input: see the `set` command and especially `set /p`. You can get information about this by typing `help set` at the prompt.
- How to test string equality: The `if` command has some info on this, type `help if` at the prompt to get some details.

When you have these things in place, you should be able to replicate the behavior of your bash script.

Comment: Anders and Gerrat: I accept both your answers as both of them were helpful to me!Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider running bash script on windows instead of porting script. See [bash-shell-for-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913912/bash-shell-for-windows). It might be easier approach.